# Command line arguments to main function while using click

Tags: python, arguments, python-click

I have this code that works fine:

```
import click

@click.command(context_settings=dict(help_option_names=['-h', '--help']))
@click.option('--team_name', required=True, help='Team name')
@click.option('--input_file', default='url_file.txt', help='Input file name for applications, URLs')
@click.option('--output_file', default='test_results_file.txt', help='Output file name to store test results')
def main(team_name, input_file, output_file):
    # function body

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()                  # how does this work?
```

As you see, `main` is being called with no arguments though it is supposed to receive three.  How does this work?

Comment: This ties into [how decorators work](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/). You've applied many of them to `click`, and presumably your method call to `main()` goes through all of those decorators before actually reaching the function body of `main()`. And each of `click`'s decorators adds one parameter in as default, since it wasn't specified in your initial call. So by the time you get down to the actual `main()` call, the decorators have provided all the default arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, this is taken care by the decorators.  The `click.command` decorator turns the function into an instance of `click.Command`.

Each of options decorators build an instance of a `click.Option` and attach it to the `click.Command` object to be used later.

This `click.Command` object implements a [`__call__` method](https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/49fe8fb9459a13aeec0d24a5997167f84c88d26f/click/core.py#L821) which is invoked by your call to `main()`.

```
def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """Alias for :meth:`main`."""
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
```

It is quite simple and simply invokes [`click.Command.main()`](https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/49fe8fb9459a13aeec0d24a5997167f84c88d26f/click/core.py#L759).

Near the top of `click.Command.main()` is:

```
if args is None:
    args = get_os_args()
else:
    args = list(args)
```

This code gets `argv` from the command line or uses a provided list of args.  Further code in this method does, among other things, the parsing of the command line into a context, and the eventual [calling of your `main()`](https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/49fe8fb9459a13aeec0d24a5997167f84c88d26f/click/core.py#L776) with the values from the `click.Option` instances built earlier:

```
with self.make_context(prog_name, args, **extra) as ctx:
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
```

This is the source of the  mysterious 3 arguments.

Comment: By the way, same rules applies if using click.argument?

Comment: @zygimantus, once the command handler is called, the Options and Arguments are just their requisite values and are no longer click objects.